# SharePoint Search connector for WikiMedia articles

Tags: 2010, search

Does anyone know about any availability of a third-party SharePoint 2010 Search connector to WikiMedia content? Crawling our internal WikiMedia content as a Web site is not desirable for the following reasons:

- Some page islands would not get indexed from a single start address
- Only article content should be indexed, i.e. navigation content should be excluded
- A Web site crawl would affect wiki articles statistics

Consequently, it would be better with a connector that crawls the MySql database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your going to find a connector ready for use.  You will probably end up having to create one yourself.

You may to review MS learning series on Search, which covers using BDC and search connectors.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ff960978

Additional you can look at the existing connectors and maybe tailor them to your needs.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/enterprisesearch/ff727944.aspx